# Verilog Xilinx - FPGA board - Cannot instantiate three multiple instances of counting module

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I want to instantiate 3 instances of my counter module. However, Xilinx will only instantiate one counter for me, not the three. Does anyone know why this is? In the RTL schematic, the 2nd two counters are connected straight to ground in their block diagrams, i.e. no logic implemented for them. Are my local parameters declared correctly?

I would really really appreciate your help. I have been staring at this problem for several hours.

Thank you so much for your help. It is really appreciated.

```
//Top Level Module:
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

//Top Level Wrapper module

module topWrapper(input CCLK, input reset, output clk, output max_tick_Green, output max_tick_Red, output max_tick_Amber);

    localparam
        M_Green = 5;
        M_Red = 3;
        M_Amber = 2;

    //Frequency scaling of CCLK 
    //clk is used in the traffic light module and is a scaled version of CCLK
    //CCLK: Frequency = 50MHz, Period = 20ns
    //clk = Frequency = 1Hz, Period = 1s
    //clkscale (frequency scaling parameter) = 1s/20ns = 5x10^7
    clock clockScalingModule (CCLK, 50000000, clk);

    //Counter for green light
    //In traffic light sequence, change from green to amber after 12 clock cycles = 120s = 2mins
    counter #(.M(M_Green)) countGreen
        (.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .state(1), .max_tick(max_tick_Green));

    //Counter for red light
    //In traffic light sequence, change from green to amber after 12 clock cycles = 120s = 2mins
    counter #(.M(M_Red)) countRed
        (.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .state(1), .max_tick(max_tick_Red));

    //Counter for amber light
    //In traffic light sequence, change from green to amber after 12 clock cycles = 120s = 2mins
    counter #(.M(M_Amber)) countAmber
        (.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .state(1), .max_tick(max_tick_Amber));


endmodule


//Counter module:

//Counter - modulo M counter - counts 0 to M-1, then wraps around

module counter

    //Parameters
    //M = number of clock cycles the counter counts = max value
    #(parameter M = 6)

    //I/O signals
    (
        input wire clk, reset, state,
        output wire max_tick
    );

    //Local parameter
    //N = number of bits in counter
    //N = ceiling(log2(M)) - definition at end of module
    localparam N = clog2(M);

    //Internal signal declaration
    reg [N-1:0] r_reg;
    wire [N-1:0] r_next;

    //Body
    //Rgister update
    always@(posedge clk, posedge reset)
        //Restart counter if reset is High or state is Low
        //State = Low if this counter's light is not currently on
        //State = High if this counter's light is currently on
        if(reset)
            r_reg <= 0;
        //Only increment counter if state is High
        //Only one of red, green, amber states is high
        else if(state)
                    r_reg <= r_next;
              else
                    r_reg <= 0;

    //Next-state logic
    assign r_next = (r_reg == M) ? 0: r_reg + 1;

    //Output logic
    //Max tick = HI when maximum count value is reached
    //Max tick = LO otherwise
    assign max_tick = (r_reg == M) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

    //Ceiling log2() function definition
    function integer clog2;
    input integer value;
    begin 
        value = value-1;        
        for (clog2=0; value>0; clog2=clog2+1)
            value = value>>1;
    end 
    endfunction

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in your counter module. Your `clog2` function returns the number of bits needed to represent `inputvalue-1`. Thus, if `inputvalue` is exactly a power of two, you can't represent `inputvalue` with the returned length.

This is probably not very clear, so let's look at what happens for `M_amber = 2`. In this case, `clog2` return 1, `r_reg` is range `[0:0]`, but you need 2 bits to represent `2 = 2'b10`. And you need to be able to represent 2, since you have the checks `r_reg == M` in your code. Said check will always fail, and Xilinx remove the logic and connects your logic to ground.

Normally, if you want to count `N` cycles in HDL, you count from `0 to N-1`. Thus, your code will be fine if you replace `r_reg == M` for `r_reg == M-1`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. You are so kind and have explained the solution very well. I have solved the problem as you said by replacing r_reg == M for r_reg == M-1 and, with this new understanding of the problem at hand, I hopefully won't make more mistakes similar to this one. Thank you!